# pip install failed on 'Temporary failure in name resolution' inspite we install local pkg

Tags: python, pip, jinja2

We want to install the Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl package by pip - on new REDHAT OS ( version 7.2 )

```
pip install Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/markupsafe/
```

I am not understand why pip failed with “'Temporary failure in name resolution” while we want to install the - Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl package by pip ?

We try also the following without successfully:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links  Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
You must give at least one requirement to install (maybe you meant "pip install Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl"?)

pip install --no-index /tmp/install/Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Processing ./Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10)

 pip install -U Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/markupsafe/

 pip install -e  Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+
```

in this case PIP - is local folder

```
pip install -e PIP/Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
PIP/Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+
```

UPDATE

```
[root@Master install_zone]# ls PIP/
Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl

[root@Master install_zone]#  pip install --no-index --find-links=./PIP Jinja2
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting Jinja2
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2)
[root@Master install_zone]#
```

WE CHECK THE resolving as: ( details are from /etc/resolv.conf )

```
[root@Master install_zone]# host  sys54.com
sys54.com has address 32.44.1.154
[root@Master install_zone]# host 32.44.1.154
17.2.21.10.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer mpsload.sys54.com.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is slightly wrong, the `find-links` argument should point to the directory the package is in, not the package itself:

> -f, --find-links       If a url or path to an html file, then
>   parse for links to archives. If a local path or file:// url that's a
>   directory, then look for archives in
>                                 the directory listing.

Above `pip install --no-index --find-links  Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl` is directing pip to look in a `Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl` directory for a package, but you've not told pip what to install.

Assuming you downloaded the file into a subdirectory called PIP, your command should be: `pip install --no-index --find-links=./PIP Jinja2`

Comment: see please my UPDAE , it still now works according to your suggestion

Comment: @Judy according to your update, `Jinja2` requires a version of `MarkupSafe` greater than 0.23, because you've told `pip` to only install from a local directory you need to ensure that all of the dependencies are present. So you'll have to download a copy of MarkupSafe and put it into that directory. You'll have to continue that process until all dependencies are resolved.

Comment: can you advice please how to find the correct - MarkupSafe ?

Comment: You can search for packages on https://pypi.org/ and download the files from there, for MarkupSafe take a look at https://pypi.org/project/MarkupSafe/#files

Comment: I try this - pip install --no-index --find-links=./PIP MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement 'MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Just run your original command for `Jinja2` that'll find the dependencies for you automatically, but either way you should be supplying the package name to `pip` not the file you want to install. `pip` figures that out.

Comment: pip install --no-index --find-links=./PIP Jinja2
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting Jinja2
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2)

Comment: still not works pip install --no-index --find-links=./PIP Jinja2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184767/discussion-between-judy-and-ajefferiss).

Comment: uname -a
Linux Master 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux